# Is it haram to develop an in store point of sale software?

Tags: halal-haram, software

As-salamu alaykum everyone

I am a software developer living in Italy.

Recently I've been contacted by a potential client who has asked me to create an in store point of sale software, think about the system that Mcdonalds uses in their stores where people go in and there's a device where they place their order and then wait for it to be processed.

This person owns an inside playground for kids, and they sell pizza and other foods that may contain haram ingredients, not only that but they also have a bar which prepares alcoholic drinks.

Now all I would be developing is the software and I have no control over what products ade added to it, meaning that the client himself will add products ecc...

Would this job be considered haram?

I guess it's like selling a fridge to a non muslim, they can store whatever they want in it.

Looking forward to hearing your responses.

May Allah grant you Jannah.

Comment: I've asked this same question in https://islamqa.info/ and I got this response from Supervisor:
Wa 'alaykum as-salam wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh From what you have stated, this job is permisisble as you are not directly aiding in anything haram. The product you are producing may be used in both ways, so you are not liable.